# Looping over multiple lists with enumerate

Tags: python, zip, enumerate

It looks like enumerate and zip don't work together in Python 3?

```
alist = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
blist = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']

for i, a, b in enumerate(zip(alist, blist)):
    print(i, a, b)
```

Returns 'int' object is not callable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `()` around `a,b`. The unpacking of the values is for the `enumerate` function which returns tuples of size two: index and value. If you further want to unpack the value item then as below:

```
for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(alist, blist)):
    print(i, a, b)
```

Comment: I tried already and 'TypeError: 'int' object is not callable'

Comment: @Alexxxx01 - on the code you posted? Because I used exactly what you put in question and added the `()` and it works

Comment: My fault: in PyCharm it worked. I restarted Jupiter and it's fine....

Comment: @Alexxxx01 - Great :)

Answer (score 1):

Since `zip` returns tuples, you can also do:

```
for i, t in enumerate(zip(alist, blist)):
    print(i, t[0], t[1])
```

Or:

```
for i, t in enumerate(zip(alist, blist)):
    print(i, *t)
```